# Как добраться до элементов коллекции C#

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Помогите разобраться, как мне добраться до `url` картинки и вывести ее в `pictureBox`
Получаю `ReadOnlyCollection<Post> wall = api.Wall.Get(-group.Id.Value, out totalCount, count);`

Ответ я получаю такого типа, то что я вижу в эрорлисте:

```
    const string json =
        @"{
            'response': {
              'count': 1449,
              'items': [
                {
                  'id': 20775,
                  'from_id': -54530371,
                  'owner_id': -54530371,
                  'date': 1422216360,
                  'post_type': 'post',
                  'text': '\'Хочу стать программистом, но не знаю, как начать и с чего начать\' — писали многие из вас нам. Мы подготовили развернутый ответ на эту тему, скомпоновав все важные идеи и мысли от матерых программистов c обсуждения на Quora.\n\nhttp://theasder.github.io/learning/2015/01/25/let-us-learn-program.html',
                  'is_pinned': 1,
                  'attachments': [
                    {
                      'type': 'photo',
                      'photo': {
                        'id': 350984773,
                        'album_id': -7,
                        'owner_id': -54530371,
                        'user_id': 100,
                        'photo_75': 'http://cs621628.vk.me/v621628086/adab/OdXug833pkY.jpg',
                        'photo_130': 'http://cs621628.vk.me/v621628086/adac/zsL4GevetNI.jpg',
                        'photo_604': 'http://cs621628.vk.me/v621628086/adad/SzZI7lCa4eM.jpg',
                        'photo_807': 'http://cs621628.vk.me/v621628086/adae/Hn1NV01xqCE.jpg',
                        'width': 620,
                        'height': 465,
                        'text': 'Original: http://s48.radikal.ru/i119/1501/ef/a985e2307823.jpg',
                        'date': 1422216360,
                        'post_id': 20775,
                        'access_key': 'ab9c7af79261b07d6e'
                      }
                    },
```

Это json, почему-то с ним мне приходится работать как с коллекцией. Как мне добраться до url картинки? foreach я могу добраться только до Attachments.

Comment: можете хотя бы написать для начала ошибку, что выдается?

Comment: JSON.Net пробовали?

Comment: Да так там изначально как коллекция читается. И любые мои попытки сделать из этого джейсон не работают.